# Reverse Bubble Sort Algorithm in C using only while loop

Tags: c, algorithm, reverse, bubble-sort

I am trying to create a reverse bubble sort algorithm. It works but the first output is a big crazy number that i dont understand. The remaining outputs seem to be sorted in descending order. Where is my code wrong?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

  void ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, int size)
  {
   int i;
   int j;
    int k;

     i = 0;
     while (i < size) 
   {
     j = 0;
     while (j < size -i) 
      {
         if (tab[j] < tab[j+1]) 
             {
                 k = tab[j]; 
                 tab[j] = tab[j+1]; 
                 tab[j + 1] = k; 
             }
     j++;
   }
 i++;
   }
   }


 int main(void) 
   {
 int tab[] = {9, 320, 0, 113, 15};
  int size = sizeof(tab) / sizeof(*tab);

   ft_rev_int_tab(tab, size);
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
    printf ("%d\n", tab[i]);
   } 
   }
```

Comment: The first wrong thing in your code is the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

`i = 0;` before `while (i < size)` is wrong. The condition `j < size -i` is equivalent to `j < size` when `i` is zero. In this case `j` will be at most `size-1` and now `tab[j+1]` is out-of-range.

It should be changed to `i = 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, int size) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        j = 0;
        while (j < size - i - 1) {
            if (tab[j] < tab[j + 1]) {
                k = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab[j + 1];
                tab[j + 1] = k;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Your condition in the nested while loop should be `(j < size - i - 1)`
because you only need to check the value from `tab[0]` to `tab[i-1]`. Your if and swap checks `tab[j]` and `tab[j+1]`, so when `i` is equal to the size of the array, you will compare it with a value outside of the array. In your example is the `tab[5]`'s value.